# Get inline-style value even if element has the value also set in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have the following element:

```
<span style="width:100px"></span>
```

and the css is:

```
span {width:50px!important;}
```

Is there a way I can get the inline-style value and ignore the css value?

Thanks

Comment: no as long as you have `!important`..

Comment: You are probably going to need display:inline-block to use width with an inline element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `element.style.width`

sample:

```
$(function(){
    alert($("span")[0].style.width);
});
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! can you tell me what the [0] does in this case though?

Comment: $(selector) gives jquery wrapper to selected native dom elements. [0] gets the first selected native dom element. you can also use `document.querySelector("span")` for selecting the native dom object for span.

Answer (score 5):

To find the applied style:

```
var span = document.querySelector('span[style]'),
    actualWidth = window.getComputedStyle(span, null).width;
```

Note that this gets the style which won, which in this case will be the one with the `!important` modifier. If you must instead try and retrieve the in-line style, regardless of whether it was applied or not, you can simply use the `style` object of the element node:

```
inlineWidth = span.style.width;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e5sE6/1/).

Do remember that, for `width` to be applied to a `span` element, it must be either `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: THanks for the explanation, very helpful but I will have to give the answer to gp, as he answered one minute earlier!

Comment: You're welcome, but I'll point out that this isn't intended to be a race. Go with the best answer for your question, not necessarily the first.